# How to retrieve an array from an AJAX call?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I make an Ajax call that needs to return (after success:...) a multidimensional array representing an SQL query :

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost/Project/ajaxmethod.php',
                        data: {action: this.title},
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(data) {

                                    //I need to use the data array here.
                        });
```

Here is the method that is called :

```
<?php

    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE;charset=utf8', 'root', '');


    $req = $bdd->query("SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM TABLE ");

    $data = ... //Here I need to transform the previous request into a multidimensional array. 
               //For exemple data[3][2] will contain the value within the third row of the second column

    echo $data; //returning the array
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant just echo an array (you can't, it an array not a simple value).

Luckily, there is a thing called JSON. In PHP you store all the information you want (in this case, your rows from the DB) in a large array and then you do `echo json_encode($array);`.

At the Javascript side you change the `$.ajax` to `$.getJSON` so that jQuery also understands that we're talking about JSON, et voila, you have a nice javascript version of your PHP array.

---

```
// I am not familiar with PDO, but something along these lines:
$allData = $req->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($allData); // Now you output a JSON version of the array
```

And then javascript

```
$.getJSON(
    'http://localhost/Project/ajaxmethod.php',
    {action: this.title},
    function(response) {
        // And in 'response' you now have a ready to use JS object)
        console.log(response);
 });
```

*You can also use `$.ajax()` if you really want to, just add a `dataType: 'json`

Answer (score 4):

**Problem**

You are trying to return am array. But as AJAX calls works on HTTP protocol, you can transfer only text, normally. So your ajaxmethod.php will print the array and the rendered page i.e. the text will be returned as it is displayed, not an array.

**Solution**

Convert the array into a JSON object using json_encode() (PHP) andreturn that. Then decode it on the page that made the ajax call, using JSON.parse() (JavaScript). This will give an array.

**Code**

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost/Project/ajaxmethod.php',
                        data: {action: this.title},
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(data) {

                                    //I need to use the data array here.
   var array = JSON.parse(data); //This is the array you want
});
```

...

```
<?php

    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE;charset=utf8', 'root', '');


    $req = $bdd->query("SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM TABLE ");

    $data = ... //Here I need to transform the previous request into a multidimensional array. 
               //For exemple data[3][2] will contain the value within the third row of the second column

    echo json_encode($data) //returning the array
}
```